# draw a straight line in swift 3 and core graphics

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, drawing, core-graphics

I'm trying to draw a single, straight line using core graphics and swift 3 However, when touchesmoved is called, it creates multiple lines instead of just a single line. Code used is below:

```
import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var drawingPlace: UIImageView!

        var startTouch : CGPoint?
        var secondTouch : CGPoint?

        override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
            let touch = touches.first
            startTouch = touch?.location(in: drawingPlace)
        }

        override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
            for touch in touches{
                secondTouch = touch.location(in: drawingPlace)

                UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawingPlace.frame.size)
                drawingPlace.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: drawingPlace.frame.width, height: drawingPlace.frame.height))
                let bezier = UIBezierPath()

                bezier.move(to: startTouch!)
                bezier.addLine(to: secondTouch!)
                bezier.close()

                bezier.lineWidth = 4
                UIColor.blue.set()
                bezier.stroke()

                let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
                drawingPlace.image = img   
            }
        }
    }
```

btw touchesEnd creates a single line but only after the user ends the touch. I want the user to see the line being drawn as they touch.
thank you.

Comment: Do you override `touchesMoved`? In case of yes, could you please add that code to the question as well?

Comment: @ReinierMelian did you mean like :: let touch = touches.last ?

Comment: @mazen your code works for me, you have missing something else of your code?

Comment: @ReinierMelian touchesEnd creates a single line but only after the user ends the touch. I want the user to see the line being drawn as they touch

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you need, i will check and add an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need **keep** the current `context` **until** the line draw process has ended, after that you need keep the current image and clear the `context`, draw the saved image again, and draw the new line. When the touch ended is called clean the current `context` and save the current image, after that start the new line draw process again

**this is the full code**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var drawingPlace: UIImageView!

    var startTouch : CGPoint?
    var secondTouch : CGPoint?
    var currentContext : CGContext?
    var prevImage : UIImage?

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        startTouch = touch?.location(in: drawingPlace)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches{
            secondTouch = touch.location(in: drawingPlace)


            if(self.currentContext == nil)
            {
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawingPlace.frame.size)
                self.currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
            }else{
                self.currentContext?.clear(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: drawingPlace.frame.width, height: drawingPlace.frame.height))
            }

            self.prevImage?.draw(in: self.drawingPlace.bounds)

            let bezier = UIBezierPath()

            bezier.move(to: startTouch!)
            bezier.addLine(to: secondTouch!)
            bezier.close()


            UIColor.blue.set()

            self.currentContext?.setLineWidth(4)
            self.currentContext?.addPath(bezier.cgPath)
            self.currentContext?.strokePath()
            let img2 = self.currentContext?.makeImage()
            drawingPlace.image = UIImage.init(cgImage: img2!)
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        self.currentContext = nil
        self.prevImage = self.drawingPlace.image
    }
}
```

## results

[image]

Comment: man thank you from all my heart thank you so much I'm stuck in this about 2 month thank you again :')

Comment: Your welcome @mazen I am glad to help you, happy coding

Comment: `if(self.prevImage != nil) {` isn't needed. draw method won't be called if prevImage is nil

Comment: You are right @LeoDabus thanks, I will update my answer

Comment: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext returns nil in both viewDidLayoutSubviews and viewDidAppear.